# Is Javascript faster at comparing integers or boolean arrays?

Tags: javascript, comparison

Comparing two integers must happen bitwise in Javascript like in any programming language, so that when I compare 8 and 9, I suppose I am comparing the sequence `1, 0, 0, 0` with `1, 0, 0, 1` (and whatever zeros precede the starting ones). Therefore this can't be far off from comparing two arrays of `boolean` types, like `[true, false, false, false]` with `[true, false, false, true]`.

My question is this: Is Javascript faster or slower at comparing `boolean` arrays `a` and `b` in Javascript than comparing integers `f(a)` and `f(b)` where `f` is a function that converts a boolean array to an integer (e.g. such that `f([false, false, true, true]) = 3`)?

Comment: Run a performance test and see?

Comment: "*Comparing two integers must happen bitwise like in any programming language*" - it seems you need to learn about [computer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture)

Answer (score 1):

> Comparing two integers must happen bitwise in Javascript like in any programming language

No. Processors can compare 32bits or 64bits (depending on the processor) in *one tick*¹. Engines would be dare to not use that.

> Therefore this can't be far off from comparing two arrays of boolean types

Modern engines perform very complicated optimizations at various stages, so there is no definite answer.

> Is Javascript faster or slower at comparing boolean arrays vs number arrays?

[Why do you ask me?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/amp/)

---

<sub>1: e.g. `CMP` for x86 processors [docs](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html)</sub>

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. But maybe someone else has and is willing to share their results. And then this question would be high up in search results the next time someone thinks to look it up.

Comment: "Part the second: Do you really need to answer that question?"

Comment: Yes, I'm writing something that needs to be fast and this is a potential bottleneck.